# Valid SSL certificate being rejected

Tags: cocoa-touch, ssl, ssl-certificate, restkit, ios5.1

I'm working on the application that uses REST web service with SSL. The web service is already in place, identifying itself with the SSL certificate. Even though the certificate seems to be valid, it is still being rejected by iOS. Below are the details:

- Web service presents the certificate chain consisting of 3 certificates, the root certificate that is present on [this list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012), the intermediate certificate and finally the web service certificate
- The method `- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)space` is called each time I send requests to the web service. The comment in RestKit code says *"server is using an SSL certificate that the OS can't validate"*, so I guess I should never reach that method, right?
- I tried to access the web service from Safari on the test device, and the certificate is automatically accepted. The same goes for the desktop browsers.
- [Sslshopper](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) says the certificate is fine.

I can connect to the web service by adding the certificate to the application bundle and handling it the same way I'd do with self-signed certificates, but I want to solve this the proper way. Any help greatly appreciated, especially if someone can point out why Safari on iOS accepts the cert, and my application does not.

**Edit:** <strike>it turns out that I've been using old RestKit version. I created the proof of concept that allowed me to dispatch some requests to my server, and with the RestKit master from today (3rd May 2012) the certificate is accepted. However, I get two calls to `connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:`, in both of them I return NO, but it manages to connect properly anyway. So, the new question is, what exactly has changed in RestKit that I can connect properly now. I need to know this because I will have to patch the old version that I'm going to use for release. I will update RestKit afterwards.</strike>

**Edit:** I need to give that back to the RestKit guys, it was not their fault. The web service that I'm trying to connect to is using some kind of gateway which is the source of the problem. There were some fixes from the gateway crew earlier in the day, that's why it worked correctly by the time I managed to perform the tests with the latest RestKit version.

Comment: If you need to do further tests, the [Qualys SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) can spot more configuration mistakes than the SslShopper test.